# SIM7020 current consumption way too high

Tags: current, low-power, power-consumption, iot

For a project I'm using the [SIM7020](https://www.simcom.com/product/SIM7020X.html) Narrowband-IoT (NB-IoT) module to send data to the cloud. The SIM7020 is controlled by an Arduino Pro Micro (ATmega32U4).

[image: Identical SIM7020 module]

Because the sensor is running on a battery, I want to have as low a current consumption as possible. I've already got the ATmega32U4 down to 35 µA, but I cannot get the SIM7020 module lower than ~7.5 mA even though the [hardware datasheet](http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim7020_series_hardware_design_v1.03.pdf) states the typical usage in power saving mode (PSM) is 3.4 µA.

After sending a message with the module it enters the PSM mode (page 16-17, chapter 6.2.5 [low power mode application](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/38/SIM7020_Series_Low_Power_Mode_Application_Note_V1.03.pdf).) This works fine. The Arduino receives `+CPSMSTATUS: "ENTER PSM"` and the status light on the module stays off. Then the current draw of the module drops to ~7.5 mA.

Schematic of the SIM7020 module chip:

[image: Schematic of the SIM7020 module chip]

Schematic of the SIM7020 module power supply:

[image: Schematic of the SIM7020 module power supply]

I'm powering the module through the VBAT/BAT pin (with 3.3 V) and I also removed the MP1470. Also fully powering off the module (with [AT commands](http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim7020_series_at_command_manual_v1.05.pdf) `AT+CPOWD` or PWR pin) doesn't change the current significantly (still stays around 7.5 mA.)

The same things happens with a second SIM7020 module (different supplier.)

Am I overlooking something in the schematic or the datasheet? Has anybody also experienced this with other modules?

Comment: Removing R9 will also save a small amount of currrent.

Comment: The MP1470 is going to take several mA no matter what you do with the main chip.

Comment: @Andyaka The text says that the op has removed the MP1470 from the board.

Comment: Did you enable slow clock (AT+CSCLK=1)?

Comment: @BruceAbbott yes, tried once but because of the changed baud rate I could not send any commands. Solved it by removing the SIM card (so it could not enter the PSM mode) and pulling UART1_DTR low so the slow clock stops.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the comments, they have put me in the right direction. I have the solution after measuring the two module boards. There are a 'few' differences between the boards and schematic.

Board one (differences from schematic):

- R1: 10kΩ
- R2: 1kΩ
- R3: 1kΩ
- R4: 1kΩ
- R5: 1kΩ
- R6: 10kΩ
- R7: 1kΩ
- **R8: 1kΩ (so not NC..)**
- R9: 33kΩ
- R15: 100kΩ

Board two (differences from schematic):

- R7: 1kΩ
- **R8: 1kΩ (so not NC..)**
- R9: 33kΩ
- R15: 100kΩ

R8 is directly connected to the PWRKEY pin ([hardware documentation](http://mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/documents/sim7020_series_hardware_design_v1.03.pdf)) and GND. Because you need to hold PWRKEY pin high for booting, there is always a current draw of (U / R = 3.3(V) / 1000(Ω) = 0.0033 =) 3.3mA. So this is part of the problem. *Note: there is also a current draw of ~0,78mA through the pullup resistor.*

I also noticed a resistor (1kΩ) instead of a capacitor on the board (C10 or C11). So there is the other 3.3mA. Also see the picture:
[image: Resistor instead of capacitor on SIM7020 module]

So summed up: 3.3 + 0.78 + 3.3 = 7,38mA with R8 removed. And thanks to 'HandyHowie' I also removed R9. This results in a current draw of 15µA @ 3.3V (measured with multimeter).